# MATLAB - how to combvec() cells?

Tags: matlab, combinatorics, cell-array

Let's say my vectors don't contain doubles. They contain cells. `combvec` refuses to accept cell values... for example:

```
m = {
    [cell1, cell2, cell3];
    [cell4, cell5];
    [cell6];
    };
```

I want to somehow get a vector of vector of cells, containing all possible combinations of cells: `[[cell1, cell4, cell6]; [cell1, cell5, cell6]; [cell2, cell4, cell6]; [cell2, cell5, cell6]; [cell3, cell4, cell6]; [cell3, cell5, cell6];];`.

How can it be done?

P.S.
The reason I'm doing this is because I have grouped items, and I want to find all combinations of them, so I thought inserting them into nx1 cells. If there's a better solution, please advise...

Comment: @Matt that wording is still confusing. So will `cell6` always be in the output, `cell4/cell5` in 50% of the outputs etc? i.e. you can't choose two items from the same row? This example seems reasonably small, why don't you show it with actual values and a couple of valid outputs?

Comment: @Wolfie yes, that's exactly what's the combvec function does. Unfortunately it does not accept vector of vector of cells, only vector of vector of doubles. I've edited to show the exact output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `combvec` with arrays of integers representing the column index, then use that to index your original array

```
C = {[{1} {2} {3}]; [{4} {5}]; [{6}]}
cv = combvec(1:3, 1:2, 1)

out = [C{1}(1,cv(1,:)); C{2}(1,cv(2,:)); C{3}(1,cv(3,:))];
```

You could generalise this like so (there may be a neater way)

```
idx = cellfun(@(x) 1:numel(x), C, 'uni', 0); % set up indexing array
cv = combvec(idx{:}); % get combinations

out = arrayfun(@(x) C{x}(1,cv(x,:)), 1:3, 'uni', 0); % index into the cell array
out = vertcat(out{:}); % concatenate results

% Result
>> out = 
{[1]}    {[2]}    {[3]}    {[1]}    {[2]}    {[3]}
{[4]}    {[4]}    {[4]}    {[5]}    {[5]}    {[5]}
{[6]}    {[6]}    {[6]}    {[6]}    {[6]}    {[6]}
```